# How do I enable text selection, copying, and pasting in a Shoes app?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is there any way to allow text selection, copying and pasting in a Shoes app?  I'm making a little utility, and it would be great if it could support this functionality.  I know shoes uses Pango/Cairo for text rendering, so I imagine there's a way to turn this on.  Anyone?  _why?

Also, _why, thanks for the great toolkit!

Much appreciated,

Bobby

Comment: indeed a shortcomming of shoes, it's also annoying you can't copy something fom the help which is a shoe app on it self of course

Answer (score 2):

Text selection, copy and paste works in edit_boxes, but it is not possible to select text blocks (such as para). Reading through the [gmane archive of the old mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes), _why had this down for [the release after Policeman](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/630/match=text+selection). There are also mentions of [Pango being the reason](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/1982/focus=1984) text selection of para was not possible.